# chrome extension elements not showing and hiding appropriately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

so this is the javascript for a chrome extension. My goal is to have the elements called tabmanageritems show in the beginning and the creategroupitems hide. Then when you press the button the tabmanageritems hide and the creategroupitems show. This is my code but when I do it, in the beginning, the tabmanageritems show and creategroupitems hide like they are supposed to, but then when I press the button, the tab manager items hide, like they're supposed to, but the creategroupitems don't show like they should. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
let tabmanageritems = document.getElementById("tabmanageritems");
let creategroupitems = document.getElementById("creategroupitems");

tabmanageritems.style.visibility = "show";
creategroupitems.style.visibility = "hidden";

let creategroup = document.getElementById("creategroup");
creategroup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    tabmanageritems.style.visibility = "hidden";
    creategroupitems.style.visibility = "show";
});
```

Comment: it is not "show" but "visible"

Comment: @Robbi Oh my goodness thank you so much I've been trying to figure this out for hours you are a lifesaver thank you so much!!